# Using c#/ASP.NET to programmatically fake a login to a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebresponse

So I'm in the process of attempting to simulate multiple logins all generating exceptions at the same time on our corporate website for the purpose of testing our logging framework (which we think there may be issues with thread synchronization).  Anyway, so I need to log in to our website programatically.  Here's what I have so far:

```
        // Block 1
        Uri url = new Uri("http://withheld");
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        string viewState = string.Empty;
        string previousPage = string.Empty;
        string eventValidation = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            viewState = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GetTagValue(strResponse, "__VIEWSTATE"));
            previousPage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GetTagValue(strResponse, "__PREVIOUSPAGE"));
            eventValidation = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(GetTagValue(strResponse, "__EVENTVALIDATION"));
        }


        // Block 2
        string username = "user01";
        string password = "password99";
        HttpWebRequest request2 = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request2.KeepAlive = true;
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string postData = string.Format("__LASTFOCUS=&ctrlCreateNewPassword_scriptManagerMaster_HiddenField=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE={0}&__PREVIOUSPAGE={1}&__EVENTVALIDATION={2}&UserName={3}&Password={4}&LoginButton=Log+in", new string[] { viewState, previousPage, eventValidation, username, password});
        byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request2.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (Stream postStream = request2.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Here's the problem
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request2.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        // At this point httpResponse.Cookies is null
        // I believe it's because the line above has actually initiated another
        // request/response which DOES NOT include the authentication cookie.
        // See fiddler output below to understand why I think that.


        // Block 3
        //Uri url2 = new Uri("http://Withheld/GenerateException.aspx");
        //http = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;
        //http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        //http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
        //HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Looks reasonably straightforward right?  Well it doesn't work.  I don't know whether I need the viewState and whatnot or not, but I figured I'd mimic what a regular browser does as closely as possible.

Near as I can tell what's happening is this:

1. We hit the page with a simple GET.  That gives us the viewstate, etc which is parsed out to be included in the following request.
2. We now post the viewstate, username, password, etc to the server using postStream.Write(). The server at this point responds with an authentication cookie, and forwards us off to /Default.aspx.
3. Now we execute reqest2.GetResponse(), but instead of getting the response that forwarded us to /default.aspx and had he authentication cookie, it looks like this line is actually causing ANOTHER request to get us the resource at /default.aspx.  The problem is httpWebResponse DOES NOT include the authentication cookie we need for the next request (which is commented out currently).

Why?  Why is this behaving in this manor, and how do I handle it properly.  Here's the output from fiddler to further explain what's going on:

Block 1 generates this request/response
Request Header:

```
GET http://withheld/Login.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: withheld
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 16:37:37 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: .EXTASPXAUTH=; expires=Tue, 12-Oct-1999 04:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16975
Response is the actual login webpage.  Omitted for obvious reasons.
```

Stepping through the code, this request/response is generated immediately following the call to postStream.Write:

Request:

```
POST http://Withheld/Login.aspx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: withheld
Content-Length: 2109
Expect: 100-continue

__LASTFOCUS=&ctrlCreateNewPassword_scriptManagerMaster_HiddenField=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2fwEPDwUJNTE1NTIxNjkxD2QWAgIDD2QWBgIDDxYCHgVjbGFzcwUQaGVhZGVyX2Jhbm5lcl9lbhYCAgEPFgQeB29uY2xpY2sFI3dpbmRvdy5sb2NhdGlvbj0naHR0cDovL3d3dy5tZG0uY2EnHwAFFmhlYWRlcl9iYW5uZXJfZW5fc21hbGxkAgUPZBYQAgcPDxYEHhdQYXJ0aWFsUmVuZGVyaW5nQ2hlY2tlZGceGUlzUGFydGlhbFJlbmRlcmluZ0VuYWJsZWRoZGQCCQ8PFgQfAmcfA2hkZAIPDw8WBB8CZx8DaGRkAhEPDxYCHg1PbkNsaWVudENsaWNrBcEBamF2YXNjcmlwdDpQYWdlX0NsaWVudFZhbGlkYXRlKCdMb2dpbkN0cmwnKTsgaWYgKFBhZ2VfSXNWYWxpZCkgeyBMb2dpbkJ1dHRvbi5zdHlsZS52aXNpYmlsaXR5ID0gJ2hpZGRlbic7IExvZ2luQnV0dG9uLnN0eWxlLmRpc3BsYXkgPSAnbm9uZSc7IExvZ2luQnV0dG9uRGlzYWJsZWQuc3R5bGUudmlzaWJpbGl0eSA9ICd2aXNpYmxlJzsgfWRkAhkPDxYCHgRUZXh0Bc0BSWYgeW91IHJlcXVpcmUgYXNzaXN0YW5jZSwgb3VyIE1EIE9ubGluZSBTdXBwb3J0IFNwZWNpYWxpc3RzIGNhbiBiZSByZWFjaGVkIGF0ICg4NzcpIDQzMS0wMzMwIG9yIGJ5IGUtbWFpbCBhdCA8YSBocmVmPSJtYWlsdG86d2Vic3VwcG9ydEBjbWEuY2EiPndlYnN1cHBvcnRAY21hLmNhPC9hPi48YnI%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%3d&__PREVIOUSPAGE=1aYW5DqTKrT4ieGPkHcnrQLIq8lEcSIVkql1EugwSQNV_5102t5D7QDmOnuQFA4Tz9Mh5-CEYpkRngMROFFeeAG12Ss1&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2fwEWCQKKr%2bXcBgKvruq2CALSxeCRDwL%2bjNCfDwKH8YSKBgKN6O7XCwKz9P38DALl3I74DwLWxI74D6Nz%2f2bCBFC%2bM9glZmEyM%2byOCTZg&UserName=user01&Password=password99&LoginButton=Log+in
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 16:36:55 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Location: /Default.aspx?locale=en
Set-Cookie: .EXTASPXAUTH=65BB5BFDD274F730E26CAEAAEB417792A764E7B8E8C6C9AC8C47FA97EF35DFACF551A53EAA6EA67D868C8A9BF55EBA758A5E724C58269028EE48F56268A204CBED19B60FC1AF58892989D9546202C037E97BF0EEE6A6281FF5EEA461BC30C5C7A71DFD64027AEB796D3FD21AE97ECFB16FF0F95C; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private, no-cache="Set-Cookie"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 140

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Default.aspx?locale=en">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Note that the above response includes an authenication cookie.
Now we run the following line of code with the intention of getting that cookie:

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request2.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

But instead the following request/response is generated in fiddler:

Request:

```
GET http://withtheld/Default.aspx?locale=en HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: withheld
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2013 16:37:38 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Location: /Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx%3flocale%3den&locale=en
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 182

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx%3flocale%3den&amp;locale=en">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I believe this is the response that httpResponse now contains.  How can I actually get the cookie to request up another protected page after the login is done?

Thanks!

Comment: I understand that all of this may be important, but I believe more people would be inclined to help you if your question was simpler; i.e. "this is the error I am getting" or "why is X variable NULL."

Comment: Maybe you should not re-invent the wheel and instead use cURL (http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: Sure I could have just posted up my code and said "How come it doesn't work?".  You can bet I wouldn't have gotten much in the way of useful replies other than questions.  This also shows (I think) that I've done some homework, and I'm not just looking to be spoon fed the answer.  If you don't want to help because it's too long, then by all means, feel free to move along.

Comment: I like the amount of detail you provided.  You could also use Firefox GreaseMonkey to automate this testing with about 10-20 lines of script.  Nothing simulates a real browser like a real browser!

Comment: @onemancat: I'm not really familiar with GreaseMonkey and not really looking to learn new libraries or scripting languages here.  I'm not sure it'd do what we need anyway since we need to simulate about 10 concurrent users.  This is just supposed to be a quick and dirty "git 'er done".  I'm sure it's possible the way I'm doing it.  I'm just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out I had two problems here.  One is that I needed to call this:

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false
```

This keeps the framework from just skipping the response that had the authentication cookie in it, and actually gives back the response we're interested in.

The other issue was that you have to create a new instance of a CookieContainer and assign it to the request.  Without having done that Response.Cookies contains no cookies.  As soon as you've assigned your own container it's populated after the response is made.  I don't know why.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get it working, but the example here did it for me: http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you login, the authentication token will be sent as a cookie from the server to your client.  You will need to store this cookie, and then re-send it with every future request.  Re-sending the cookie tells the server that you have been authenticated as a certain user.

To get the cookies that were sent in response after you logged in:

```
HttpCookieCollection loginResponseCookies = Response.Cookies;
```

This collection will include the auth cookie, any session cookies, etc.

Then, just re-send these cookies with every subsequent request, and the server will authenticate you as a result.

```
foreach(HttpCookie loginResponseCookie in loginResponseCookies)
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(loginResponseCookie);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explict enough with my question.  I understand I need to send the authentication cookie with further responses.  The issue is that httpResponse.Cookies is null.  I've updated the first code snippet with comments to explain.  Thanks for taking the time to answer though.